# tradingview strategy pine script : how to open a position in an exact moment

Tags: pine-script, trading

i am trying to write a strategy on tradingview , the main idea is that i have calculated an greatest swing value for a long open(bgsv) and sell open(sgsv)

```
study(shorttitle="sGSV", title="Greatest swing value",overlay=true)
src = input(open)
lenght = input(4, minval=1 ,title="lenght")
multi = input (1.8,title="multiplier")
hx= src>close[1] ? close[1] : src
lx= src<close[1] ? close[1] : src
hg= (high-hx)
lg= (lx-low)
bgsv = (sma(hg,lenght))*multi+hx
sgsv= lx-(sma(lg,lenght))*multi
plot(bgsv,offset=1, color=color.green)
plot(sgsv,offset=1, color=color.red)
```

I need to write strategy that will open a long in the moment when the  price reaches or opens above bgsv[1] (if that's not possible i would like to use the high instead )
and opens a short in the moment when the price reaches or opens below sgsv[1](if that's not possible i would like to use the low instead )

i tried with the function crossover and crossunder but it opens a position on the next bar not the one i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done, as only OHLC values are available on historical bars.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html#backtesting-and-forwardtesting